# React component opens all child states

Tags: reactjs, state

I have a list of courses with student icon on them. When clicked on student icon it opens a modal and displays all assigned students on the course.

The problem I am having is when I click on one of the course to open the modal, it opens the modal for all the other courses. I know its to do with the state behaviour but I can't seem to figure out how best to tackle this problem.

Following is my code:

```
class CourseDetails extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        autobind(this);

        this.state = { openStudentsAssignedToCourseModal: false };
    }

    closeStudentsAssignedToCourseModal() {
        this.setState({ openStudentsAssignedToCourseModal: false });
    }

    render() {
        const { store } = this.props;
        const { openStudentsAssignedToCourseModal } = this.state;

        return store.allCourses.map((course) => {

            return (
                <Container key={course.id}>
                <p>{course.name}</p>
                    <UsersIcon
                        size={25}
                        onClick={() => {
                            if (course.listOfStudents.length > 0)
                                this.setState({
                                    openStudentsAssignedToCourseModal: true
                                });
                        }}
                    />
                    {openStudentsAssignedToCourseModal && (
                        <StudentsOnCourseModal
                            course={course}
                            isOpen
                            close={() => {
                                this.closeEmployeesAssignedModal();
                            }}
                        />
                    )}
                </Container>
            );
        });
    }
}
```

Modal:

```
class StudentsOnCourseModal extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        autobind(this);
    }

    render() {
        const { course, isOpen, close } = this.props;
        const s = course.listOfStudents.length === 1 ? '' : 's';

        return (
            <Modal
                isOpen={isOpen}
                close={close}
                width="large"
                bgDismiss={false}
            >
                <ModalHeader>
                    <h2>Assigned students</h2>
                </ModalHeader>
                <ModalBody>
                    <p>
                        There {s === '' ? 'is' : 'are'}{' '}
                        <b>{course.listOfStudents.length}</b> student{s}{' '}
                        currently assigned to the course <b>{course.name}</b>.
                    </p>
                    <StudentsContainer>
                        {course.listOfStudents.map(student => (
                            <StudentItem key={student.id}>
                                <StudentCard
                                    name={student.name}
                                    link={`/student-profile/${
                                        student.id
                                    }/personaldetails`}
                                    imageHref={
                                        student._links.image
                                            ? student._links.image.href
                                            : undefined
                                    }
                                />
                            </StudentItem>
                        ))}
                    </StudentsContainer>
                    <OutlineButton
                        onClick={e => {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            close();
                        }}
                    >
                        Close
                    </OutlineButton>
                </ModalBody>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't capturing the selected course so it was opening all of them. Fixed it by introducing a new state to capture the selected value and passed that into the modal.